# CSRF Implementation does not working with OAM

Tags: angular, spring-security, csrf, csrf-token, x-xsrf-token

Our application is a spring boot with angular. Due to security reasons, we need to implement CSRF. We have done the implementation but still getting 403 forbidden. W**e do use OAM login authentication**. In spite of setting HTTPonly to false,in-browser we see that it is not false. We can well see the token.

```
HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN', headerName: 'XSRF-TOKEN'})
```

This is the code in the angular frontend.

We have done implemented the below code at backend:
Configuration class:

```
http
  .httpBasic()
  .and()
  .csrf() // csrf config starts here
  ignoringAntMatchers(CSRF_IGNORE) // URI where CSRF check will not be applied
  .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()) // defines a repository where tokens are stored
  .and()
  .addFilterAfter(new CsrfFilter(), CsrfFilter.class); 

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    CookieCsrfTokenRepository repo =  CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
    /*repo.setHeaderName(CsrfFilter.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME);*/
    repo.setHeaderName("XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repo;
}
```

And the filter code:

````
private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
    return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                    .getName());
            if (csrf != null) {
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", csrf.getToken());
                cookie.setPath("/");
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    };
} ```

Any help and suggestions are welcome.
We are in doubt that may be OAM authentication does not go with CSRF implementation.
````

Answer (score 0):

Angular has some built-in protections against common web-application vulnerabilities and attacks such as `XSS` and `CSRF`. See the following page:
https://angular.io/guide/security

Comment: Yeah, we have implemented exactly like what is mentioned in that page.